# Jenkins pipeline script to checkout code from tfs with credential

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, continuous, content-delivery-network

I am pretty new in Jenkins and continuous integration.Here I mentioned the problem I faced while using groovy in Pipe line.

```
node('node-name')
{
    stage 'Checkout code'

    bat 'http://devtfsappd00.avi.com:8080/tfs/Example_DevCollection'
}
```

Just a very basic pipeline script. Which says :

> 'http:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   ERROR: script returned exit code 1
>   Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to checkout files from TFS from within the Jenkins pipeline script:

```
checkout([$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm', credentialsConfigurer: [$class: 'AutomaticCredentialsConfigurer'], projectPath: '$/TFS/Server_Path', serverUrl: 'http://tfs-server-url/', useOverwrite: true, useUpdate: true, workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}'])
```